# Passing array to a store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to pass an array of 20k IDs to my stored procedure param in order to update a certain table.

Instead of running 20k update queries separately, I want to run 1 query to update all, it should improve my performances.

Any knows I can I pass a param to my stored proc?

I understood that NVARCHAR(MAX) is limited to 8000 chars, is it possible at all to send such a huge data using stored proc param?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Table Value Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) instead. See [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). A TVP is exactly as the name implies: a parameter that is a table. You assign to it from your client code a DataTable and the procedure (or you ad-hoc SQL codE) receives the entire DataTable as a parameter.This is an MSDN copied example:

```
// Assumes connection is an open SqlConnection.
using (connection)
{
// Create a DataTable with the modified rows.
DataTable addedCategories = CategoriesDataTable.GetChanges(
    DataRowState.Added);

// Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.
string sqlInsert = 
    "INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)"
    + " SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName"
    + " FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;"

// Configure the command and parameter.
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(
    sqlInsert, connection);
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";

// Execute the command.
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```